# Identify whether the object is going or returning in postgis

Tags: postgis

Where does the distance remaining for a given vehicle to reach the destination return me, but if the route of the variable v_line is a circuit, where the origin is the same destination and has an intermediate point, I do not know with identifying if the vehicle is going or coming back

```
SELECT
    ST_Length(
        ST_LineSubstring(
            line,
            least(ST_LineLocatePoint(line, pta), ST_LineLocatePoint(line, ptb)),
            greatest(ST_LineLocatePoint(line, pta), ST_LineLocatePoint(line, ptb)))::geography
    )  AS dst_line
FROM (
    SELECT
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING('|| v_line ||')',4326)::geometry line,
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| v_atual ||')',4326)::geometry ptb,
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| v_final ||')',4326)::geometry pta
```